# Where to get mp4 samples?

Tags: react-native, video, video-streaming

I'm currently working on a react-native app. The app us supposed to store data with mongoDB, but at the moment I'm only working locally and mostly on the Frontend and basic logic. One of the app's functions is to display videos. I'm using react-native-video for that purpose. As for the source, I wanto to to use the format source={{uri: <url>}}. I only have one sample video (Big Buck Bunny) but I can't seem to find any other links to other videos. So my question goes like this:

**Does anybody know another place I could get mp4 video samples?**
I cant use youtube or things like that. I need for the link to be for the actual mp4 file. http://....mp4

When I searched on google for "Video sampling" or "mp4 samples" or any other similar searches, I couldn't find anything aside the same video I already have. (Which I kind of dislike btw, I find it pretty ugly, but that's  beside the point)